# Can lightning set stuff on fire?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Notch has just implemented lightning. I'm now too terrified to open up my treehouse map in case a storm burns it to the ground! Is this possible?

#### Update

I've unanswered this question, now that fire behaves differently in 1.6.

Comment: And now I regret turning my buddys area into an ALL wood area. Ohh well. Atleast it was griefed by natural causes.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I just watched a huge treehouse burn to the ground because of a lightning strike. Rain ***DOES NOT ALWAYS*** put out fires. Now all my wool pixel art is in danger as well. Had to revert to a backup.

Caught the last few seconds of the destruction. Mind you, this used to be a huge treehouse that spanned at least 64x64 and up to the ceiling.

[image: burning treehouse]

[image: burning treehouse]

Comment: Well that sucks.

Comment: Ouch that sucks. The fire probably started somewhere where it was sheltered from the rain and grew until the rain couldn't put the fire out.

Comment: Argh! I need lightning rods and I need them now! My treehouse is quite a lot larger than that one (was)...

Comment: I just returned from 15 minutes of mining and saw my whole wooden building on fire. That sucked. The rain put the fire out after a few minutes when not much was left of the building.

Answer (score 14):

In the preview of 1.5 that Notch showed, you can see lightning strike the ground and cause a fire.

However, as per [elliya's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20362/can-lightning-set-stuff-on-fire/20582#20582), **the rain doesn't always extinguish the fire**.

Comment: Blast. Beat me by 8 minutes.

Comment: Is there ever lightning under dry conditions?

Comment: Also, for those of you who embed YouTube videos, be sure to use the time anchor if you need a YouTube video to forward to a particular moment. [YouTubeTime](http://youtubetime.com/) does this for you, in case you don't know [how to do it by hand](http://www.wikihow.com/Link-to-a-Certain-Time-in-a-YouTube-Video).

Comment: Ahh, forgot about time anchors; thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @Kevin Y - No worries, I added one in for you anyways :)

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize that and added a time anchor on top of your time anchor, *facepalm*. Thanks for adding it. :)

Comment: @Sadly Not According to the [MC Wiki page](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Rain) on rain, thunderstorms are a part of the rain weather condition and not their own kind of weather, so I would assume they can only exist when it is raining.

Comment: I just saw a lightning strike take out a huge wood structure on SMP.

Comment: Hmm, that sucks. However, my answer *did* **correctly answer** what the question, just that I assumed the rain would put out the fire from what was written on the Minecraft Wiki. (Kind of disappointed at the downvote...)

Comment: Sounds like my lighthouse on an SMP server is in severe danger.  The observation deck is made of wool.

Answer (score 1):

yes, lightning will set things on
fire here is a image of it:[image: lightning here!]

note that i am using the /summon command
you can use the link below:

[lightning](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lightning)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is yes, it does. It's a bit like a flint and steel -- it will light a fire anywhere but only spread on
wood and wool.